# Using Regex For Checking Specific String

Tags: php, regex

I have a PHP code to check a string inside collection of strings, my code something like this:

```
$string = '01122028K,02122028K,03122028M-1';
$search = '03122029M'
echo preg_match('/\b' . $search . '\b/', $string);
```

It returns TRUE...

How can I do with my regex to return it FALSE, I want it only return TRUE when the string in variable $search is actually match in variable $string, 
so $search = "03122029M" would return FALSE
   $search = "03122029M-1" would return TRUE

Thank you

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752829/regular-expression-for-exact-match-of-a-word

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a regular expression.

```
echo in_array($search, explode(',', $string));
```

Comment: Thank you Barmar, I think this is the good & quick solution for my problem. It works..
:-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the boundary spearators you are using: `\b` includes the `-`.

You could separate on whitespaces and commans instead, using a character class. Also include the start of line, and of line in the test to catch cases at end of line:

```
preg_match('/(^|[\s,])' . $search . '([\s,]|$)/', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you really need a regular expression here. Moreover, you'd also be opening up yourself to an escaping nightmare.

If you add a comma to the start and end of `$string`, you can match the entire `$search` as a single entity by wrapping it in commas as well:

```
echo (strpos(',' . $string . ',', ',' . $search . ',') !== FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

\b includes - in what you're matching.  Match specifically off of commas instead - you can do this by just adding a comma to the start and end of the string.

```
$string = '01122028K,02122028K,03122028M-1';
$string = ','.$string.','
$search = '03122029M'
echo preg_match('/,' . $search . ',/', $string);
```