# Visual Studio - Productivity Power Tools - RegEx folder name Color Coding

Tags: visual-studio-2015, productivity-power-tools

Path in my project:

**C:\Unicorns\Fart.Rainbows\Classes\someFiles.cs**

How do I color code tabs based on file path containing the following?:

**"\Fart.Rainbows\"**

It looks like my question is asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967583/regular-expression-to-match-folder-name-with-productivity-power-tools-color-codi), but I can't seem to get the regex right.

The following works in a [regex tester I tried](https://www.regex101.com/), but not in Prod Power Tools:

```
\b\\Fart\.Rainbows\\\b
```

[image: General]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing regular expression from

```
\b\\Fart\.Rainbows\\\b
```

to

```
.*\b\\Fart\.Rainbows\\\b.*
```

See if this helps.