# Attempting to distinguish read-only vs non in Custom Document Well with Reg. Ex

Tags: regex, visual-studio, productivity-power-tools

Custom Document Well with Productivity Power Tools for Visual Studio 2017 comes with the ability to change the color of tabs according to Project and/or something they call Reg. Ex.

To my understanding this is just ordinary regular expression but out of the box they have a tag, or something, they call `\[read only\]`. Something I can't find any documentation about anywhere, or anyone attempting to do anything with? One of the default Reg. Ex.'s look like this:

`.*\.(cpp|c|hpp|h)[ ]*(\[read only\])?$`

I thought that meant that there is some functionality for checking if the actual file is read only or not, but I can't for my life figure out how to do that, this is what I've tried so far:

`.*\.(cpp|c|)`

`.*\.(h|hpp)[ ]*(\[\])?$`

`.*\.(h|hpp)[ ]*(\[writable\])?$`

But the Read Only always seem to take precedence.

What I want to achieve is have different colors on my tabs depending on the read only state of the file, and I only want this because I saw the read-only flag in the reg-ex.

Comment: would this help? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40042433/visual-studio-productivity-power-tools-regex-folder-name-color-coding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40042433/visual-studio-productivity-power-tools-regex-folder-name-color-coding)

Comment: What are you trying to do? If the default regex is executed first and it matches, your patterns won't be even tried.

Comment: The thing is it shouldn't match since the file isn't read-only. I just assumed that the Document Well had some extended functionality of RegEx where you have this read-only state available. And for your second question: "What I want to achieve is have different colors on my tabs depending on the read only state of the file"