# How to match exact sequence with Pattern compile

Tags: java, android, regex, linkify

I'm trying to use `Linkify` but can't seem to get the `Pattern.compile()` part down.

Let's say i have a string like `blah blah hi Hello world! can you match me?`

i want to match and linkify ONLY `Hello world!` and nothing else. i was trying to play around with this regex:  `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\bHello world!\\b");` but it doesn't seem to be matching at the exclamation mark.

what's the best way to match for an EXACT sequence of characters?

Comment: Look into what `Pattern.quote()` does.

Comment: @DavidWallace you should write it as an answer so i can upvote it. i needed to have done `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("Hello world!"));`

Comment: I'm not convinced that's what your problem was, though.  `!` isn't supposed to be special in a regular expression.  Chances are you had a different bug, which you've now unknowingly removed.

Comment: @DavidWallace feel free to try out the pattern with the `!` and then without the `!`. that seemed to be the only problem for me

Comment: `\b` does not match the boundary after `!` because `!` is not part of the `\w` character class and thus doesn't form a word boundary.

Answer (score 0):

Using regexs, you can use `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^Hello world!$");
```

Also this question is a repeat of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752829/regular-expression-for-exact-match-of-a-string).