# remove exact match word from a string

Tags: regex, r

I would like to remove the word "amp" in the below sentence.

**original**:

```
x <- 'come on ***amp*** this just encourages the already rampant mispronunciation of phuket'
```

**What I want**:

```
x <- 'come on this just encourages the already rampant mispronunciation of phuket'
```

However, if I used `gsub`, the "amp" in the word of "rampant" will be removed as well which is NOT the case I want. Can I know what function should I use in this case?

```
> gsub("amp","", x)
[1] "come on  this just encourages the already rant mispronunciation of phuket"
```

Comment: how about `gsub(" amp ", " ", x)`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
gsub("\\bamp\\b","", x)
# [1] "come on  this just encourages the already rampant mispronunciation of phuket"
```

The `\\b` means word boundary.

Comment: +1, however matching with `\b` like this might introduce problems in some cases. See the comments to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752829/regular-expression-for-exact-match-of-a-word/13065780#13065780.

Answer (score 1):

You could also split the string into words, and then compare:

```
x <- 'come on this just encourages the already rampant mispronunciation of phuket'
split_into_words = strsplit(x, ' ')[[1]]
filtered_words = split_into_words[!split_into_words == 'amp']
paste(filtered_words, collapse = ' ')
[1] "come on this just encourages the already rampant mispronunciation of phuket"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just find the occurrence of "amp" that has a space in front.

```
> gsub("\\samp", "", x)
## [1] "come on this just encourages the already rampant mispronunciation of phuket"
```

where `\\s` means space.  This is more readable as

```
> gsub(" amp", "", x)
```