# Search for exact word or phrase in Flash Builder's "Search" tool?

Tags: regex, eclipse, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

How do I search for an exact match to a phrase or word in Flash Builder's search tool?

For example, in my project I have a class with a function named "removeEvent". If I search on it, I get all instances where "removeEventListener" is used and of course that is not helpful.

I have searched on the web but only come up with similarly unhelpful false hits (how ironic).

It appears I can use regex but I don't know how to do that and trying [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5752852/840992) to a regex question was no help

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable the regular expression option and then use the below regex.

```
\bremoveEvent\b
```

`\b` called word boundary which helps to do an exact match.. `\b` matches between a word charcater and non-word character, vice-versa..