# Regex - Matching two numbers before a certain string

Tags: regex

How would I match the two numbers before the word "min"

Sample string:

```
15min
```

I would want to match:

```
15
```

Edit:

I've tried matching the pattern, but how do I get the two characters before?

```
\W*((?i)min(?-i))\W*
```

Comment: _This is too difficult for me, please give me the code_, this is what your question is saying right now, add your attempts.

Comment: Because it's a terrible question... Juste open a simple regex tutorial...

Comment: [How to Regex](http://regexone.com/)

Comment: Yet something like this gets 36 upvotes.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752829/regular-expression-for-exact-match-of-a-word

Comment: Hi @CMS.  Note how old that post is, the site has evolved somewhat since 2011.  Also - it shows that there are many old answers that basically answer your question.  If you need to know what regex expression matches a digit, the link provided above will help.  If you need to capture the group of digits preceding the literal `"min"` it will help too.  Have a look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for up to date guidance on the way to ask questions here to get the best help.

Comment: I can see you've now edited in what you've tried.  Can you now explain what you thought that would do and what it matches on the input string `15min` vs. what you'd like to get? Also - would you like to extract single digit numbers as well (e.g. `5min`)? 3 digit numbers? spaces between number and `"min"`?  Also - are you happy with how to extract a particular bracketed group in whatever environment you are implementing this in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a regex that just extracts the first number in the string:

```
^\D*(\d+).*$
```

If the number must be in front of *min*, then you can write it as:

```
^\D*(\d+)min.*$
```