# Replacing a portion of a string with an exact matching

Tags: c#, .net

I just want to replace a portion of a string only if matches the given text.
My use case is as follows:

```
    var text = "<wd:response><wd:response-data></wd:response-data></wd:response >";
    string result = text.Replace("wd:response", "response");

    /*
     * expecting the below text
      <response><wd:response-data></wd:response-data></response>
     *
     */
```

I followed the following answers:

[Way to have String.Replace only hit "whole words"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143642/way-to-have-string-replace-only-hit-whole-words)

[Regular expression for exact match of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752829/regular-expression-for-exact-match-of-a-string)

But I failed to achieve what I want.

Please share your thoughts/solutions.

Sample on 
https://dotnetfiddle.net/pMkO8Q

Comment: This seems more a question how to remove the namespace from an XML element. Doing this with `string.Replace` or Regex might have unexpected consequences. Are you going on to read this XML or are you simply mutating and saving?

Comment: Hi @John,
Thanks for your prompt reply.
I'm just mutating and saving on my local.
I just want the xml document without the ns.
any thoughts?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987135/how-to-remove-all-namespaces-from-xml-with-c

Comment: @RSF that's Word XML, not just a string. Never mind that string manipulation is a bad way to deal with XML, *document processing* is more than just modifying XML elements.

Comment: @RSF as for the replacement you want to perform *why*? There's nothing wrong with namespaces in XML. Removing the namespace will result in *invalid* XML and a broken document. .NET's XML classes and the Open XML SDK can handle namespaces without any problems

Comment: @RSF `I just want the xml document without the ns. any thoughts?` why do you want to do that? What is your *actual* question?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should really be parsing and manipulating XML *as* XML, using functions that know how XML works and what's legal in the language. Regex and other naive text manipulation will often lead you into trouble.

That said, for a very simple solution to this *specific* problem, you can do this with two replaces:

```
var text = "<wd:response><wd:response-data></wd:response-data></wd:response >";
text.Replace("wd:response>", "response>").Replace("wd:response ", "response ")
```

(Note the spaces at the end of the parameters to the second replace.)

Alternatively use a regex similar to `"wd:response\s*>"`

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the string `wd-response` [`in a capturing group`](https://regex101.com/r/eo5ue5/3) and replace using [`Regex.Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netframework-4.8) using the [`MatchEvaluator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) like this.

Regex explanation - `<[/]?(wd:response)[\s+]?>`

- Match `<` literally
- Match `/` optionally hence the `?`
- Match the string `wd:response` and place it in a capturing group enclosed with `()`
- Match one or more optional whitespace `[\s+]?`
- Match `>` literally

---

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = "<wd:response><wd:response-data></wd:response-data></wd:response >";
        string replacePattern = "response";
        string pattern = @"<[/]?(wd:response)[\s+]?>";
        string replacedPattern = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, match =>
        {
            // Extract the first group
            Group group = match.Groups[1];

            // Replace the group value with the replacePattern
            return string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", match.Value.Substring(0, group.Index - match.Index), replacePattern, match.Value.Substring(group.Index - match.Index + group.Length));
        });
        Console.WriteLine(replacedPattern);
    }
}
```

---

Outputting:

```
<response><wd:response-data></wd:response-data></response >
```

Comment: How is the output of this different from OP's original code?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve your result as per your .net fiddle is use the replace as below.

string result = text.Replace("wd:response>", "response>");

But proper way to achieve this is parsing using XML