# finding exact match for a word in pandas series

Tags: python

I have a data frame given below

```
news                 score
testing tools           12
test match              32
he is testing           332
test is done             23
```

I want a result like this

```
news                        score
test match                   32
test is done                 23

ddf[ddf['news'].str.contains('test', regex= False)]

ddf[ddf['news'].str.contains('test', regex= False)]
```

Comment: What's the problem/error?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
pattern = '/\btest\b/'
ddf[ddf['news'].str.contains(pattern, regex= True)]
```

For more information about regex pattern read this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13065780/2754195

Comment: Hi Mehdi,
Thanks for your response.

I find out 
ddf[ddf['news'].str.contains(r'\b\W?test\W?\b', regex= True)]

Comment: Your welcome, if it helps you to find out the solution, please accept it :)